# Como faço para uma DIV aparecer quando posicionar o mouse em cima de uma img?

Tags: html, css

Estou com dificuldade para fazer um menu no site que estou montando, quero que quando o usuário posicione o ponteiro do mouse em cima da imagem no canto superior esquerdo, abra um menu no mesmo local onde está localizado o header e mantenha nesse local até o mouse sair da área.

Print de como está o corpo HTML atualmente.
[image: Print da tela até o momento]

```js
Código JS em branco
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'california';
    src: url('font/Hai_California.ttf');
    src: url('Hai_California?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('font/Hai_California.ttf') format('svg'),
      url('font/Hai_California.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    /* 
    
        Usa uma fonte externa (baixada ou internet) e disponibiliza para que 
        caso o usuário não tenha a mesma instalada na sua máquina, seja feito o
        download da fonte.
    
    
    */
  }
html, body {
        background-color: #ffff;   
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}
img.menu_icon {
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
}
.menu_icon:hover .menu {
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: -1;
}
img.logo {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1366px;
    height: 220px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: rgb(245,183,46);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(245,183,46,1) 0%, rgba(249,219,92,1) 100%);
    color: black;
}
.menu {
    opacity: 0.75;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1366px;
    height: 220px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #cc444b;
    color: white;
    display: none;
    
}
.menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
#header h1 {
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.logo {
    margin-top: -250px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}
/*

    Centraliza a imaem dentro do header

*/
.logo_nome {
    margin-top: auto;
}
.logo_nome a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.conteiner img {
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 150px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 7px #6b722d;
    font-size:  70px;
    font-family: california, cursive;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br"> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="sortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="fotos/logo.png"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" >
        <title>Sal de Ouro</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Teste</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Teste</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Teste</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Teste</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Texte</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
        <div id="header">
            <img class="menu_icon" src="fotos/menu.png" >
            <h1>Sal de Ouro</h1>
            <img class="logo" src="fotos/logo.png" /> 
        </div> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/index.js" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá...

Talvez a sugestão abaixo ajude.

Basicamente a estratégia é a seguinte: O botão que tem o menu, na verdade é o próprio menu que irá expandir.

Para garantir o fucionamento, ele é fixado num tamanho arbitrário e suficiente para exibir apenas o icone de menu. Também e configurado o `overflow:hidden`. Isso irá garantir que o restante do menu não apareça.

No `:hover` ele tem seu tamanho alterado para permitir a exibição do conteúdo completo. Nesse ponto, pode-se esconder o botão de menu, ou não.

```css
div.header-menu{
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 120px;
}

div.menu-icon{
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}

div.bt-menu{
  display: block;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 0.5s, height 0.8s;
}

div.bt-menu:hover{
  width: 180px;
  height: 120px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

div.bt-menu:hover div.menu-icon{
  display: none;
}

div.bt-menu:hover ul.menu{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

ul.menu li{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-menu">
  <div class="bt-menu">
    <div class="menu-icon">
       Menu <!-- aqui o icone de menu -->
    </div> <!-- .menu-icon -->
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div> <!-- bt-menu -->
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Olá não utilizaria o CSS para isso, vou mostrar em JS como faria, uma observação você está utilizando display none então precisa adicionar o z-index na class .menu conforme abaixo.

```js
function apareceMenu()
{
    document.querySelector(".menu").style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.menu {
    opacity: 0.75;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1366px;
    height: 220px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #cc444b;
    color: white;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    
}
```

```html
<img class="menu_icon" onmouseover="apareceMenu()" src="fotos/menu.png" >
```

```html
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'california';
    src: url('font/Hai_California.ttf');
    src: url('Hai_California?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('font/Hai_California.ttf') format('svg'),
      url('font/Hai_California.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    /* 
    
        Usa uma fonte externa (baixada ou internet) e disponibiliza para que 
        caso o usuário não tenha a mesma instalada na sua máquina, seja feito o
        download da fonte.
    
    
    */
  }
html, body {
        background-color: #ffff;   
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}
img.menu_icon {
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-top: 15px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
}
.menu_icon:hover .menu {
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: -1;
}
img.logo {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1366px;
    height: 220px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: rgb(245,183,46);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(245,183,46,1) 0%, rgba(249,219,92,1) 100%);
    color: black;
}
.menu {
    opacity: 0.75;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1366px;
    height: 220px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #cc444b;
    color: white;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    
}
.menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
#header h1 {
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.logo {
    margin-top: -250px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}
/*

    Centraliza a imaem dentro do header

*/
.logo_nome {
    margin-top: auto;
}
.logo_nome a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.conteiner img {
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 150px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 7px #6b722d;
    font-size:  70px;
    font-family: california, cursive;
}
</style>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br"> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="sortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="fotos/logo.png"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" >
        <title>Sal de Ouro</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="menu" onmouseout="someMenu()">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Teste</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Teste</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Teste</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Teste</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Texte</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
        <div id="header">
            <img class="menu_icon" onmouseover="apareceMenu()" src="fotos/menu.png" >
            <h1>Sal de Ouro</h1>
            <img class="logo" src="fotos/logo.png" /> 
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
<script>
function apareceMenu()
{
    document.querySelector(".menu").style.display = 'block';
}

function someMenu()
{
document.querySelector(".menu").style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ainda assim não está funcionando :c

Comment: Coloquei o código completo, mas as únicas alterações foram essas!

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, mas mesmo assim não funcionou

Comment: Ué quando clica no executar aqui no stack funciona, qual erro está apresentando?

Comment: no stack está funcionando normal, mas no corpo html nao funciona, nao apresenta nenhum erro

Comment: Olá, agora deu certo, estava esquecendo de colocar o arquivo js no arquivo html, agora só preciso que o menu desapareça quando o ponteiro do mouse sair da área

Comment: atualizei o código para subir também!

Comment: Deu certo! obrigado pela ajuda <3

Answer (score -4):

Tente usar os pseudo-elementos `:hover` ou o `:active` no header, o hover é ativado quando o mouse está posicionado em cima do elemento e o active quando ele é clicado.

```
.header:hover{
   /* lógica para mostrar o menu */
}
```

Comment: Já estou usando o :hover (como mostrado no código), mas não está funcionando.